# how to print the default value of annotation interface in main java program

Tags: java, annotations

I am new with an annotated interface:

```
@interface 
Test {
    public String getInfo() default "hi";
}

@test
class TestImpl implements Test
{
    public String getInfo(){return getInfo();}
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        TestImpl impl=new TestImpl ();
        impl.getInfo();
    }
}
```

Actually, I am totally confused with this, I want to print the default value of my getInfo() methods. and don't know how to use it and also the advantages of the annotated interface.

if some buddy has an idea about it, plz make changes of my above code as the printable format of default values, and also if it id possible then give me the URL from where I can read more about the annotated interface.

Thanks,
Subodh Ray

Comment: Don't forget to format your code next time. Have a look at the Markdown help if you don't know how to do it.

Comment: You will have to do it reflectively.

Comment: ok next time no mistake thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class TestImpl { // not implementing the annotation interface
```

and then:

```
Test annotation = TestImpl.class.getAnnotation(Test.class);
String info = annotation.getInfo();
```

Note that usually annotation attributes are not defined as getters. So `info()` instead of `getInfo()`

Update: you need `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` on your annotation class. If it is not there, the annotation is not preserved at runtime.

Comment: @subodh - update the question by _adding_ the new code, so that I can see if you didn't miss something